# Change background of a Button using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

I would like to change the background image when a button is pressed and i would like it to stay changed for ever..

The problem in this code, is when i close the app, the button is disabled as expected, but the background isnt changed.
Here is my code :

```
day2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("day2", true);
            if  (firstrun) {
                day2.setEnabled(true);
                day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Day02.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);


                } else {
                    day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
                    day2.setEnabled(false);

                }

            myVib.vibrate(50);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? Please elaborate.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code and after your if you have to change the `SharedPreferences` values, as follows:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean("day2", true);
        if  (firstrun) {
            day2.setEnabled(true);
            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Day02.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            //This line
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("day2",false).commit();


            } else {
                day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
                day2.setEnabled(false);

            }

        myVib.vibrate(50);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add your boolean value like given code in shared prefrence`btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("rb1", rb1.isChecked());
        editor.commit();

        finish();

    }
} );`
```

Answer (score 0):

On first click you need to check Preferences each time you click the button and save the value to the `getSharedPreferences` also set the background, by the time the user click the button twice it will run the `else` block and wont change the background again.

**sample:**

```
        public void onClick(View view) {

        if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(main_Activity.this).getString("day2", "").length() == 0)
        {
            //will only run once it will only work in first click of button
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(main_Activity.this).edit().putString("day2", "1").commit();

            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dumbbell1); //set the background forever
            day2.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            //will only work on second click of button and so on..
            //will run when you click button again
        }

    }
```

put this outside your onclick after you initialized your button

```
`Button day2 = (Button)findViewById(....);`

    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(main_Activity.this).getString("day2", "").length() != 0)
        {
            day2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dumbbell1); //set the background forever
            day2.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

**my code that works:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(   this).getString("day2", "").length() != 0)
    {
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image); //set the background forever
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).getString("day2", "").length() == 0)
            {
                //will only run once it will only work in first click of button
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit().putString("day2", "1").commit();

                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image); //set the background forever
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

the `activity_main` xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @MobiusApps phone or emulator?

Comment: @MobiusApps uninstall it first. and install, so all the SharedPreferences that was saved will be deleted

Comment: @MobiusApps have you added the if statement after you initialized.. just like above code?

Comment: Yes, and it does not work.. for some reason even when i try to set a background before the button clicked.

Comment: @MobiusApps try my sample code above and run it.. when you click on the button it will change background..

Answer (score 0):

first create a method within your class or within a helper class

```
    private static void setButtonPref(Context ctx, String clicked)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("clicked", clicked);
    editor.commit();
}
```

then in your button click

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
      setButtonPref(context, "yes");
   }
```

then in your `activity`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

then check for the pref if it has been

```
if (sharedPref .getString("clicked", "yes").equals("nope")){
    // it never been clicked
}else{
    // it has been clicked before do whatever you want with the background
}
```

Comment: My method is working fine for me, it's just the background that isn't working.